# Mapping of Dynamic fields in RestfulController POST (save) method

Tags: spring-boot, grails, groovy, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

How do I enable RestfulController to auto-map or even manually map the dynamic fields to domain classes implementing MongoEntity? I have a domain class as below:

```
class Company implements MongoEntity<Company> {
    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    String name
    String email
    String phone
}
```

And I have a RestfulController setup for CRUD operations as below

```
class CompanyController extends RestfulController<Company> {

@Transactional
    def save(Company company) {
        if(company.hasErrors()) {
            respond company.errors
        }
        else {
            company.insert(flush:true)
            respond company, status: CREATED
        }
    }
}
```

When I POST a request with some additional JSON fields, how do I get them auto-mapped to gorm_dynamic_attributes ? Currently the company object does not return any information on the dynamic attributes. Another problem I am facing is that `request.JSON` is also null so I cannot manually map either. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need `MongoEntity`? it works perfectly either with `@Entity` for standalone, or simply by putting the class under `grails-app/domain`. Also this thing `String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()` is HIGHLY suspicious

Comment: Using MongoEntity just for code clarity. But my issue doesn't resolve with using @Entity. Also what do you find suspicious about UUID thing? I want my ids to be UUID based instead of ObjectId.

Comment: @injecteer I also tried using id generator: 'uuid2' and it doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: what's wrong with mongo's cluster-wide unique ids? they should work like charm. I didn't try `id generator:'uuid'`, but what really works is `id generator:'assigned'` and that should work for your case. Also I would move the id generation from the init block of your class into `beforeInsert()`, as otherwise it could mess up with loading logic

Comment: @injecteer Thanks. But our project protocol wants string based ids in UUID format. Also beforeInsert() is not getting called for Mongo entities. Please suggest what should be my approach then

Comment: @injecteer To clarify beforeInsert() is not getting called for Mongo entities where id is defined as assigned attribute

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that the problem is not in data binding of your controller, but rather in persisting of the domain class instance.

I would change the domain class like so:

```
import grails.gorm.annotation.Entity

@Entity
class Company {
    String id
    String name
    String email
    String phone

    def beforeValidate() {
      if( !id ) setId UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    }  

    static mapping = {
      id generator:'assigned'
    }
}
```

to use the `assigned` generator. You could put your id generation either in the controller / service code, or leave it inside the domain class' `beforeValidate`. In the later case pay special attention to when the id shall be generated, as `beforeValidate()` is called pretty often. Also note, that inside `beforeValidate()` a setter must be called.

I tested the similar domain class of mine with `save()` and `insert()` and in both cases that works like charm.